# Pythonic multiple text tables within one text file to CSV conversion

Tags: python, csv, text, readfile

I'm still learning python and was wondering what a pythonic way (aka less is more) of coding the following problem.

Due to the wonders of 1990s technology, a text file is dumped to the server everyday with csv tables in it. That's right - one text file with *two* csv tables.

Goal: To parse out the csv tables and make them into two different csv files.

File looks like this:

```
start of file
blah blah
blah blah
blah blah

+--------
,tbl1, tbl1,
+--------
,data, data,
,data, data,
.....
,data,data
+--------
blah blah
blah blah
blah blah
+--------
,tbl2, tb2,
+--------
,data, data,
,data, data,
....
,data, data,
blah blah
blah blah
```

**Issue: Table 1 is varying in length.**

I need to be able to extract table 1 no matter what the length of the table is and make it a CSV file.

I have

```
def lp_to_csv(in_file_name, out_filename):
#open the input & output files.
inputfile = open(in_file_name, 'rb')
csv_file = out_filename
out_csvfile = open(csv_file, 'wb')

#read in the correct lines
my_text = inputfile.readlines()[117:-8]
del my_text[1]
for row in my_text:
    #cycle through to find the end
    if row[0] != ",":
        print "excludeded: " + row

#convert to csv using "," as delimiter
in_txt = csv.reader(my_text, delimiter = ',')
#hook csv writer to output file
out_csv = csv.writer(out_csvfile)
#write the data
out_csv.writerows(in_txt)

#close up
inputfile.close()
out_csvfile.close()
```

but that code only makes 1 csv file and it includes the second block of 'blah blah'.

I think I know how to make it two csv files (create a subroutine that creates a csv file with the my_text object, but how do I cut out the blah blah and how do i trigger when to chop it into 2 tables?

Can anyone direct me for a nice pythonic way?

ANSWERED:
Very similar to below answer:
I created a subroutine that created a list of where the delimiter `+-----` was. Since it's always in groups of three, First, Heading Row, End.

Then I chunk into groups of three the list.

Then activate the table making code on each group of three.

Pretty handy so far & stateless which is nice.

Comment: That is not CSV, so the CSV Python module is not going to help you much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No state variables, please.

```
delimiter = '+--------'
try:
    while True:
        skip_junk(src, delimiter)
        table = read_table_name(delimiter)
        process_table(table, src, delimiter)
except ...
```

and let any function to raise appropriate exception (EOF reached; table name missing, some other format violation, whatever else) to break the loop, and don't forget to process them.
Normally, each function just returns when the delimiter is encountered.

Comment: That is a good pattern, assuming the format *is* actually stateless (which it looks like it is).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the tables begin and end with `+--------`. You can use that to parse the file.

You should keep one state variable - `inside_csv`. At first initialize it to `False`. Now, go over the lines of the file, one by one. If you see `+--------`, flip `inside_csv` (from False to True or the other way around).

If you see another line, check `inside_csv`. If it's true, write the line to a CSV file. If it's not, ignore it.

Don't forget to switch CSV files when you finish the first and start the second.

Comment: I'm sorry - i missed one `+-------` per table. the header row is surrounded by them.

Comment: OK, so start processing CSV lines after the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but here's an approach

```
current_table = 0
headers_seen = 0
tables = [[], []]
for line in inputfile.readlines():
    if line == '+--------':
        headers_seen += 1
        if headers_seen == 2:
            current_table = 1
        elif headers_seen == 5:
            current_table = 2
        else:
            current_table = 0
        continue
    if not current_table:
        continue
    tables[current_table].append(line)
```

Feels like it could be cleaner, but I wanted to handle an arbitrary number of tables; then I realized there's that weird header issue, so it should `headers_seen == [2, 5]` would have to be smarter (something like = 2 or greater than 4 and headers_seen %2 == 1).